# How to change segmentcontrol color while loading the iphone application?

Tags: iphone, colors, segments

i want to change the color of the segment color while loading the application.

or is it possible to change the color of the segmentcontrol according to the NavigationBar header/title color?

Provide any solution with any code snippet or any useful link,which would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in the documentation for `UISegmentedControl` under the `tintColor` property, e.g.:

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

If you prefer, you can use the `-setTintColor:` method:

```
[segmentedControl setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Put this in your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear: method.